# How can I obtain a MSVC compiler warning's description in CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I'm using CMake to build a project which consists of several internal static libraries.
The libraries are built from source.
Some of them cause compiler warnings.
I am disabling those warnings by `target_compile_options` command.

Whenever a warning is suppressed, I write a message at VERBOSE level to see which warnings are disabled for which libraries.

I would like to automate creating the `message` when a warning is suppressed.

```
function(disable_msvc_warning target visibility warning_no)
    message(VERBOSE "Disabling warning for ${target} at ${visibility} visibility: C${warning_no} ...")
    target_compile_options(${target} ${visibility} "/wd${warning_no}")
endfunction()
```

Example usage:

```
disable_msvc_warning(my_target PRIVATE 4267)
```

Expected message:

```
-- Disabling warning for my_target at PRIVATE visibility: C4267 'var': conversion from 'size_t' to 'type', possible loss of data
```

Is it possible to automatically fill `message` according to the compiler error number?

Comment: no, you'd have to write your own lookup table from warning code to message

Comment: huh. I see you accepted the other answer. I see several problems with it. You can take a look at my comments there.

Comment: @user Thanks for your impressive answer :) I have accepted the other one because it solves the markdown escape characters problem. I agree that relying on Python is a con, but I directly use the generated file in the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex and cleaning the text from markdown syntax (**,\," etc.) has done with Python.

**Python code for Regex**

```
import re
import requests

# Download the content of the URLs and process each one
urls = [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/main/docs/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4000-through-c4199.md",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/main/docs/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4200-through-c4399.md",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/main/docs/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4400-through-c4599.md",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/main/docs/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4600-through-c4799.md",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/main/docs/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4800-through-c4999.md"
]
output = ''
for url in urls:
    # Fetch the page content
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content.decode('utf-8')

    # Replace `some` and `*asterisks*` with `some` and `asterisks`, respectively, while ignoring `\*`
    content = content.replace("<br /><br />","")
    content = content.replace("`", "")
    content = content.replace(r"\<", "<")
    content = re.sub(r"\*([\w\s-]+)\*", r"\1", content)
    content = re.sub(r"\\\*", r"*", content)

    # Define the regex pattern
    pattern = r"\b(C\d{4})\b.*?\|(.*)\|"

    # Find all matches in the content
    matches = re.findall(pattern, content)

    # Append the matches to the output
    for code, message in matches:
        output += f"{code.upper()}: {message.strip()}\n"
        output = re.sub(r'"(\n)$', '\n', output)

# Write the output to a file
with open('warnings.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

.txt file has to be on the same directory with CMakeList.txt

**warnings.cmake**

```
# Read the file contents into a variable
file(READ "warnings.txt" FILE_CONTENTS)

# CMake only uses ; as delimiter for lists. Every line has \n at the end by default.
#  ";" is used in descriptions. To prevent false splitting, ";" changed into a non-used character in the txt which is "é".
string(REPLACE ";" "é" FILE_CONTENTS_LIST "${FILE_CONTENTS}") 
string(REPLACE "\n" ";" FILE_CONTENTS_LIST "${FILE_CONTENTS_LIST}")
#  Now every ";" is can be used for splitting the file contents into lines

# Regular expression pattern 
# Look for any match starts with CXXXX: and ends with anything other than newline. 
set(WARNING_REGEX "^(C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\\: ([^\n]*)$")


# Process each line separately
foreach(LINE ${FILE_CONTENTS_LIST})
    # Check if the line matches the regular expression pattern
    string(REGEX MATCH "${WARNING_REGEX}" MATCHES "${LINE}")
    
    # Extract the captured groups using CMAKE_MATCH_* variables
    if (CMAKE_MATCH_COUNT GREATER 0)
        set(WARNING_CODE "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
        set(WARNING_DESCRIPTION "${CMAKE_MATCH_2}")
        # Add the warning code and description to the list
        list(APPEND WARNING_CODES ${WARNING_CODE})
        list(APPEND WARNING_DESCRIPTIONS ${WARNING_DESCRIPTION})
        # Print the warning code and description
        #message(STATUS "Warning code: ${WARNING_CODE}")
        #message(STATUS "Warning description: ${WARNING_DESCRIPTION}")
    endif()
endforeach()

function(get_msvc_warning_description CODE)
    set(warning_desc "" PARENT_SCOPE)
    list(FIND WARNING_CODES "C${CODE}" index)
    if(index EQUAL -1)
        message(SEND_ERROR "Warning Code: C${CODE} has no match")
    else()
        list(GET WARNING_DESCRIPTIONS "${index}" desc)
        # Warning descriptions have ";" in them, so we have to bring ";" back.
        string(REPLACE "é" ";" desc "${desc}")
        set(warning_desc "${desc}" PARENT_SCOPE)
    endif()
endfunction()

function(disable_msvc_warning target visibility warning_no)
    get_msvc_warning_description(${warning_no})
    message(VERBOSE "Disabling warning for ${target} at ${visibility} visibility: C${warning_no} ${warning_desc}")
    target_compile_options(${target} ${visibility} "/wd${warning_no}")
endfunction()
```

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include(warnings)

get_msvc_warning_description(C4189)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4189: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4844)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4844: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4928)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4928: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4944)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4944: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4953)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4953: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4499)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4499: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4024)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4024: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4337)
message(STATUS "Disabling C4337: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C5205)
message(STATUS "Disabling C5205: ${warning_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C2900)
```

I tried bunch of different warning codes and also a warning code that doesn't exist(C2900). This is the output:

- Disabling C4189: 'identifier': local variable is initialized but not  referenced
- Disabling C4844: 'export module module_name;' is now the preferred syntax for declaring a module interface
- Disabling C4928:illegal copy-initialization; more than one user-defined conversion    has been implicitly applied
- Disabling C4944: 'symbol': cannot import symbol from 'assembly1': as 'symbol' already exists in the current scope
- Disabling C4953: Inlinee 'function' has been edited since profile data was collected, profile data not used
- Disabling C4499: 'function' : an explicit specialization cannot have a storage class    (ignored)
- Disabling C4024: 'function': different types for formal and actual    parameter 'parameter_number'
- Disabling C4337: cross-referenced    type library 'library1' in 'library2' is being automatically imported
- Disabling C5205: delete of an abstract class 'type-name' that has a non virtual destructor results in undefined behavior
- Warning Code:C2900 has no match

Comment: hm. I'm personally less of a fan of the idea of requiring every person building the project to have python installed. Going pure CMake is less burden on people building the project. Add to that the fact this solution doesn't run the python script as part of the configuration process (see [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html)), which is just an unnecessary extra manual step added to the builder's plate.

Comment: do you ever change the `é`s back to semicolons? Or do you just leave them like that forever after converting semicolons into them? I think either I'm blind, or you don't.

Comment: For example what does yours do when printing C4013? What happens to the semicolon there?

Comment: @user Thanks for pointing out the "é" situation. I don't how it happened but my 2 functions had ended up not being here. I fixed it now. Also, I'd like to mention that your answer helped me a lot since I barely know CMake. I had to use Python because CMake does not support lookbehind. Also I cleared the markdown just enough to work with current version of warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You could pull [the warnings documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-by-compiler-version) with [`file(DOWNLOAD)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download) and then "scrape" it with some shoddy string parsing:

```
set(msvc_warnings_md_url_base "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/main/docs/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-")
set(msvc_warnings_md_parts "c4000-through-c4199" "c4200-through-c4399" "c4400-through-c4599" "c4600-through-c4799" "c4800-through-c4999")
foreach(msvc_warnings_md_part ${msvc_warnings_md_parts})
file(DOWNLOAD
  "${msvc_warnings_md_url_base}${msvc_warnings_md_part}.md"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/msvc_warnings/${msvc_warnings_md_part}.md"
)
file(READ "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/msvc_warnings/${msvc_warnings_md_part}.md" msvc_warnings_md)
string(REPLACE ";" "\;" msvc_warnings_md "${msvc_warnings_md}")
#message("${msvc_warnings_md}")
set(msvc_warnings_md_li_regex "\\|[^\n]*(C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])[^\n|]*\\| *([^\n]*) *\\|")
string(REGEX MATCHALL "${msvc_warnings_md_li_regex}" msvc_warnings_list "${msvc_warnings_md}")
#message("${msvc_warnings_list}")
foreach(li ${msvc_warnings_list})
  string(REGEX REPLACE "${msvc_warnings_md_li_regex}" "\\1\\2" li "${li}")
  #message("li: ${li}")
  string(SUBSTRING "${li}" #[[begin]] 0 #[[length]] 5 key)
  string(LENGTH "${li}" li_length)
  math(EXPR val_len "${li_length} - 5")
  string(SUBSTRING "${li}" #[[begin]] 5 #[[length]] "${val_len}" val)
  string(REPLACE ";" "\;" val "${val}")
  string(REPLACE "[" "\\\[" val "${val}")
  list(APPEND msvc_warning_keys "${key}")
  list(APPEND msvc_warning_vals "${val}")
  #message("${key}: ${val}")
endforeach()
endforeach()
#list(LENGTH msvc_warning_keys msvc_warning_keys_length)
#list(LENGTH msvc_warning_vals msvc_warning_vals_length)
#message("msvc_warning_keys_length: ${msvc_warning_keys_length}")
#message("msvc_warning_vals_length: ${msvc_warning_vals_length}")

function(get_msvc_warning_description CODE OUTPUT_VARIABLE)
  list(FIND msvc_warning_keys "${CODE}" index)
  list(GET  msvc_warning_vals "${index}" desc)
  set("${OUTPUT_VARIABLE}" "${desc}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Example usage:

```
get_msvc_warning_description(C4189 C4189_desc)
message("C4189_desc: ${C4189_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4267 C4267_desc)
message("C4267_desc: ${C4267_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4373 C4373_desc)
message("C4373_desc: ${C4373_desc}")
get_msvc_warning_description(C4998 C4998_desc)
message("C4998_desc: ${C4998_desc}")
```

Output of the above example:

```
C4189_desc: 'identifier': local variable is initialized but not referenced
C4267_desc: '*variable*': conversion from 'size_t' to '*type*', possible loss of data
C4373_desc: '*derived_class*::*function*': virtual function overrides '*base_class*::*function*', previous versions of the compiler did not override when parameters only differed by const/volatile qualifiers
C4998_desc: EXPECTATION FAILED: *expectation*(*value*)
```

Comment: It is enlightening to see the whole problem can be solved with pure CMake. I believe that Markdown escape characters problem can be solved as well. However, it would make the code barely sustainable. Anyway, I would upvote twice if I could. Great work!

Comment: @Burak I'd write the code to strip the markup, but unluckily for me, some of the usages of markdown special characters that should be escaped in the source are not escaped (which I'm pretty sure is okay with a proper Markdown renderer, but I have no idea how I'd handle it with the simple subset of regex that CMake supports, and it seems like the other answer you accepted doesn't properly handle this either, and just strips out text that should be rendered as text in what would be the rendered Markdown). Ex. in C4179's "`'//*'`", which would be "`'//\*'`" if escaped.

Comment: Actually, the other answer handles that case properly, see [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75986563/5). It may not be possible with Cmake since it does not fully support regex as you said. Maybe regex parsing the html pages works, they don't have escape characters, right? :)

Comment: @Burak well, it's more of a coincidence that it ends up working for that scenario. what about a scenario where the first of the two asterisks is escaped? Doesn't seem to be handled there yet (though technically it doesn't need to... right now (given the current markup)).

Comment: I'm sure there is a Python library that converts a Markdown script to the rendered text. It is good enough now.